# Процессор греется не на шутку

Tags: ubuntu

Поставил Убунту себе на ноутбук  (Samsung RV-515 AMD Vision 1.66 Ghz, 2 ядра). Работает сообразительнее, чем на 7 или 8. Хотел уже привыкать к Убунту, на заметил, что сильно греется процессор. Проверял температуру - 65 - 70 градусов(даже когда машина ничего не делает).

Comment: Может быть дело не в операционной системе? Сколько ноутбуку лет? Имеет смысл проверить, не высохла ли прослойка между.. нет, не креслом и клавиатурой :) а процессором и радиатором. Или м.б. пыли в радиаторе чрезмерное количество. Высокая температура в простое - имхо, верный признак того, что нелады с теплоотводом.

Comment: Тут даже есть возможность того, что подгорел какой то конденсатор и не гасит напругу как надо.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно разборка ноута и чистка системы охлаждения с проверкой / заменой пасты...

[@Malus](/users/230/malus) - количество пакетов ни при чем - это ж не винда, не запускает все одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде убунта ставит много лишних пакетов, запусти top глянь что грузит

Answer (score 0):

Только разборка, продувка, чистка!!!

Answer (score 0):

Разборка, чистка, замена термопасты. Если ноут старый, возможно потребуется замена тепловых трубок

Answer (score 0):

Давно уже заметил, что некоторые ноуты в плане терморегуляции конкретно заточены под OEM-ную ОС, и никуда больше. Из личного опыта: ноут, заточенный под Win7 намертво перегревался при загрузке с лайвов WinXP и Knoppix, но нормально работал с лайва Win7, и даже с лайва Висты!

Answer (score 0):

нет, пока не будет чистки и желательно замены термопрослойки судить далее точно нельзя. Те кто разбирал ноуты знают какой войлок из пресованной пыли набивается в место между вентелем и радиатором. Уберете его а там уже дальше видно будет из-за него или из0за лишних пакетов лиукса

Comment: Вот я как раз так и думал! И разобрал, и почистил! И только потом попробовал разные ОС!